# AHK/Auto Hot Key Loop Key Press

Tags: autohotkey

I want to make a script that presses a key and does it over and over. But I don't want to hold the key forever.
This is the code:

```
x::
While (GetKeyState("x", "P")) {
    Send e
    Sleep 500 
}
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2 ; allows max 2 threads to be triggered by the same hotkey 
; (for stopping the thread with the same hotkey that launched it)

toggle := "" ; initialize variable

$x::  ; The $ prefix prevents the Send command from triggering the hotkey itself
    toggle := !toggle ; changes value of the variable toggle between 1 (true) and 0 (false)
    While (toggle)  ; While true
    {
        Send e
        Sleep 500 
    }
return
```

Comment: Thanks and did you put something so i can stop it or no?

Comment: Press x once again to stop the loop.

Comment: it didn't stop it

Comment: Try it first in Notepad. Does it work there?

Comment: oh its working now thanks i think i just forgot to copy something